# Making Environments Using xtemplate

Tags: environments, best-practices, latex3, xtemplate

The examples for `xtemplate` show how to make document commands, but I haven’t seen anything involving environments.

If I were to define an environment using `xtemplate`, what would the best approach be? The two ways I immediately think of are:

1. Define a single object, `env`, and two templates, `start` and `end`.
2. Define two objects, `env-start` and `env-end`.

The way `xtemplate` works gives me the impression that it’s focused on commands only; is that the case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I think there is nothing about "making document commands" in `xtemplate`. This package provides commands like `UseInstance`, which can be used for creating both commands and environments. "Creating things" itself, should be done via `xparse`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't directly define either commands or environments with `xtemplate`. You probably want to use `xparse` for that. Although I suppose you logically could define a separate template or instance for the ending part, I'm having trouble envisioning a use case for that. When are you going to need to have different parameters for the beginning and and of the environment?

The way I use template instances within environments is to have the code in `\DeclareTemplateCode` handle the initialization at the beginning of the environment and then create a separate function to handle the closing. Then your environment defined with `xparse` can just call those two functions, which is in keeping with the `expl3` philosophy of keeping the user interface separate from the coding layer.

Here's an illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xtemplate}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareObjectType{test}{0}

\DeclareTemplateInterface{test}{default}{0}
{
  linenum-modulus : code = 5
}

\DeclareTemplateCode{test}{default}{0}
{
  linenum-modulus = \modulolinenumbers[#1]
}
{
  \AssignTemplateKeys
  % just something for illustration
  \linenumbers
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \smith_testme_stop:
{
  % Do cleanup here
}

\DeclareInstance{test}{first}{default}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{testme}{}
{
  \UseInstance{test}{first}
}
{
  \smith_testme_stop:  
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{testme}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{testme}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```